Download PDF in Laravel 9 using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf give us a pdf file corrupted
Trying to download file using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf from HTML render view
        // Generate the PDF from the HTML content
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($contract_document)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')
                        ->setOption('zoom', 1.2)
                        ->setOption('footer-center', '')
                        ->setOption('footer-font-size', 5);

   
    return $pdf->download($ad_id . '.pdf');

It downloads a corrupted file. If I try to open it in Firefox's PDF viewer, I get the following error:
Invalid or corrupted PDF file.

PDF.js v4.7.18 (build: 9735a840a)
Message: Invalid PDF structure. viewer.mjs:12184:13
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { message: "Invalid PDF structure.", name: "InvalidPDFException", stack: "BaseExceptionClosure@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.mjs:453:29\n@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.mjs:456:2\n" }

can you please advice ?

Maybe there is something wrong with your $contract_document. Did you try the minimal example from their github page ? $pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');

I've tried it , it give me the same issue

Someone seemed to have the same issue and seemed to end using something else : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/770

it's working by using wkhtmltopdf extension and download   https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy and https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk
thank you in advance

Please consider upvoting my previous comment if it helped you.
